# How to read files relatives to the .dart file?

Tags: dart

Suppose the following files:

> lib/src/program.dart
>
> lib/src/file.txt

I want to read file.txt contents from program.dart using a library that contains *readingFunction(path)*:

```
//program.dart
String fileContents = library.readingFunction("./file.txt");
```

This throws an error, because the current path is the one in which execution was launched (or the package path if executing with *pub run*).

How could I achieve the reading with relative path instead of being forced to use "./lib/src/file.txt" path?

Comment: Sounds like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859376/get-script-path-in-dart-analog-dir-constant-in-php

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294237/how-to-read-file-from-an-imported-library

Comment: Very informative. Thanks, learnt much there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Resource](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/resource) package.

It allows you to read files that are embedded in packages. Files are specified with a special URL that looks like `package:package_name/path/to/file.txt` (same as used in `import` statements).

Comment: Package discontinued

Comment: there is a fork [resource_portable](https://pub.dev/packages/resource_portable)